# Unable to get sessions variable value generated in php side to display on web page with .html extension

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Basically I have login.html page, userAuth.php and main.html page. What I want to do is that after I login with my credentials, userAuth.php does all querying with mysql and if login is successful redirects to main.html page. In userAuth it also starts session . Now in main.html I want to display the username that we obtain from userAuth but I am unable to do so.
Here is userAuth.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){

    $username=$_POST['username'];

    /*encrypting the password recieved*/
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);

    /*connect to db */
    $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","usermanagement");
    if(!$connection){
        echo "Sorry! Cannot connect to the database";
    }

    $query="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(!$result){
        echo "query not executed successfuly";
        exit();
    }

    /*a row or more returned . Record found*/
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !=0 ){

        /*start session*/
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        $username=$_SESSION['username'];
        header("Location: /protected/main.php");
        echo $username;
    }
    else{
        header("Location: /protected/login.html");
        echo "Invalid username or password";
    }

}
```

Here is my main.html:

```
<div id="Header">
    <div id="Header1">
        <button id="logout" type="button">Logout</button> <p id="welcome">
            Welcome
            <script>
                var userNameInSession;
                $.get('/scripts/userAuth.php',function(data){
                    userNameInSession=data;
                    console.log("user in session: "+userNameInSession);

                });
            </script>

    </p>
    </div>
```

I am doing console.log just to check if i am recieving username but i get a blank there.

Comment: `userAuth.php` expects `username` and `password` parameters to be passed with `POST`. You're not sending any parameters.

Comment: You aren't posting anything to `userAuth.php`.  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: umm... you are checking in your php file for existence of `username` and `password`, also you are checking the `$_POST`array, but sending a get request, a lot of mistakes :\

Comment: @LukePark : my login.html POSTS that to userAuth

Comment: But when you call `userAuth` from `main.html`, you're not posting anything, so it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @Gudz Daniel: thats what my confusion is. my login.html successfully does a post to userAuth.php. However after redirecting to main.html on successful login how will i exactly do a get of that username?

Comment: @Barmar : I want to just GET a  value from main.html and not post anything

Comment: @Barmar I'm going to have to test that for myself to see if that doesn't throw anything. brb

Comment: @Barmar Ok, you're right, my mistake. will scratch off some of my comments. I always thought that if there was an echo in either position, that would throw a headers notice. There's no need for the echo then; extra code for nothing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- If that were so, how would you ever send custom headers along with other output? e.g. `header("Content-type: application/json"); echo json_encode($var);`

Comment: @Barmar you're right. However and as I edited my comment above, the echo will never appear, so there's no need for that extra code (echos) if they're going to use a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `else` block that just returns the session variable.

There's also no point in echoing anything when you do a redirect with `header()`. The redirect will be followed instead of displaying the output of this script.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){

    $username=$_POST['username'];

    /*encrypting the password recieved*/
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);

    /*connect to db */
    $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","usermanagement");
    if(!$connection){
        echo "Sorry! Cannot connect to the database";
    }

    $query="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(!$result){
        echo "query not executed successfuly";
        exit();
    }

    /*a row or more returned . Record found*/
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !=0 ){

        /*start session*/
        session_start();

        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        $username=$_SESSION['username'];
        header("Location: /protected/main.php");
    }
    else{
        header("Location: /protected/login.html");
    }

} else {
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
    } else {
        echo "Not logged in";
    }
}
```

Comment: header and echo, *ahem*

Comment: I was fixing that just as you typed the comment.

Comment: let me try your solution @Barmar. Give me few mins

Comment: WOrks like a charm @barmar. thank you so much. Could have never thought of an else block and now it all makes perfect sense. thank you once again.